# PHP - mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I try to get num_rows:

```
SELECT * from Store_Product_List where ProductType = 'some' order by ProductPrice asc
```

But i got this error:

```
Warning: mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
```

Full code:

```
    $dbgetstorelist = new DB_MSSQL;
    $dbgetstorelist->query("SELECT * from Store_Product_List where ProductType = '$storecategory' order by ProductPrice asc");
var_dump($dbgetstoremethod->num_rows());
    for($i=0;$i < $dbgetstorelist->num_rows();++$i) 
    { //do something }
```

num_rows() function from class:

```
function num_rows() {
    return mssql_num_rows($this->Query_ID);
  }
```

var_dump of $dbgetstoremethod->num_rows() is:

```
int(3)
```

Comment: And where does `$this->Query_ID` get set?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix different methods of accessing the database. If you're using DB_MSSQL, stick to those methods for accessing the result. My recommendation would be to install the correct PDO drivers for your database, and use PHP's PDO class

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you've set the value for the property $this->Query_ID.

Maybe try:

```
$dbgetstorelist = new DB_MSSQL;
$dbgetstorelist->Query_ID = $dbgetstorelist->query("SELECT * from Store_Product_List where ProductType = '$storecategory' order by ProductPrice asc");
for($i=0;$i < $dbgetstorelist->num_rows( );++$i) 
{ //do something }

function num_rows() {
 return mssql_num_rows($this->Query_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Presumably, something is wrong with your query.  You should print out the query string after variable substitution to see if there is a problem and if you can run it somewhere else.

However, if you want to get the number of rows, let the database do the counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM Store_Product_List 
WHERE ProductType = '$storecategory';
```

A possible problem in your queries is embedding the value of the variable in the query itself.  Instead, you should be using parameterized queries.